# php mysql login header issue

Tags: php, mysql

hello ive created a simple login for a php mysql assignment:

```
<?php
/*Initialize session*/
session_start();

/*Store form data in variables*/
$username = $_POST['username'];
$password = $_POST['password'];

/*Connect to the database*/
$conn = mysql_connect("localhost", "twa174" , "a3wgrrzn")
or die ("Could not connect: " .mysql_error());

mysql_select_db("twa174", $conn)
or die ("Could not find Database: " . mysql_error() );


/*Create empty error log*/
$errors = '';

/*Check for login attempt*/
if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    if(!isset($username) || empty($username)) $errors .= '<p>Please enter a 
username!</p>';
    if(!isset($password) || empty($password)) $errors .= '<p>Please enter a 
password!</p>';
    /*Initialize login sequence on attempt*/
    if(empty($errors)){
        $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM school_info WHERE schoolID ='".$username."'");
        $numrows = mysql_num_rows($query);
        if($numrows!=0){
            while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)){
                $dbusername= $row['username'];
                $dbpassword= $row['password'];
            }           
            if($username==$dbusername&&$password==$dbpassword){
                header("Location: leavers.php");
            } 
            else {
                $errors .= '<p>Incorrect login details</p>';
            }
        }
    }
}

?>

<?php echo($errors);?>














<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
  "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd"> 

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">

<head>
    <title>Login PHP Page</title>
    <link href="assign2.css" rel ="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
</head>


<body>
<form action = "login.php" method="post">
<table>
<tr> <td>Username:</td>
<td><input type="text" name="username" />
</td> </tr>
<tr><td>Password:</td>
<td><input type="password"  name="password"/> </td></tr> 
<tr><td> <input type="submit"  name="submit" value="Submit" </td> 
<td> <input type="reset" name="reset" value="Reset"</td></tr>
</table>

</form>
</body>

</html>
```

it is meant to redirect upon correct entry of the username and password, but instead it stays on the same page no matter correct or incorrect.

i've had abit of trouble with headers in the past.

i'm not sure if i have one too many brackets or that it wont redirect because i already have scripts above my header function.

Anyone know where i've gone wrong?

Comment: Your script is vulnerable to SQL injections.

Comment: try to use `exit` after header function `header("Location: leavers.php"); exit;`

Comment: Does it go to `else`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At first glance, I can see the if-else is not proper. Your else is inside your if. Thay may be causing problem.

```
 if($numrows!=0){
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)){
    $dbusername= $row['username'];
    $dbpassword= $row['password'];}

    if($username==$dbusername&&$password==$dbpassword){
    header("Location: leavers.php");}

    else{$errors .= '<p>Incorrect login details</p>';}}}}
```

Also,output the $dbusername and $dbpassword after while loop to check if they are same as $username and $password(because there may be duplicate entries in database.

Comment: nice, i will give that a go.

Comment: the script is fixed but still doesnt get redirected

Answer (score 0):

if you are having header issues, maybe you could try use ob_start() - at the beginning of the file - before session_start()

```
<?php ob_start(); ?>
```

It helps me.

Answer (score 0):

First make sure you're not outputting anything before calling `header()`. I've had similar issues in the past. 
You can also place `ob_start()` before `session_start()` and `ob_flush()` after calling `header()`. `ob_start()` simply makes sure no active output is sent from the script except the headers.